# Future tenses (asking about plot in tv shows)

Tags: present-tense, future-tense

So, the situation is following: I am watching a TV show that my friend has already watched prior to me. I want to know something about the plot. How should I ask her?

1. "Are they going to find her in that room?"
2. "Will they find her in that room?"

Answer (score 1):

Both work correctly in this scenario; it sounds better to say "are they going to" as it implies that the person being adressed likely knows the answer. This is based on no rule but simply a stylistic choice in my case

Comment: @ConfusedSoul One should accept an answer they find helpful, not an answer that appears to be correct.

Comment: Correct answers will likely be helpful ones... At least when I provide my answers I hope them to correct hence helpful. May I inquire the reason of edit of my post?

Comment: @ConfusedSoul Sugarcoating doesn't help much in that it has nothing to do with the exact question. I edited the question by the same token.

Comment: I consider it politesse, and that it creates an atmosphere of friendliness and conviviality.

Comment: @ConfusedSoul I understand, but there have been discussions about this, but it's been decided that it'd be better to dispense with it entirely and stick to the point.

Comment: I don't agree with *no rule but simply a stylistic choice.* As pointed out in [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/64925/2637) to a related question, *you use **going to** about future events that are already planned, and **will** about future events decided at the time of speaking*. That "rule" may not be rigorously applied in every context, but it's a very common distinction familiar to all native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, I am aware of that difference between going to and will. Are you saying that in this context, you'd rather use will?

Comment: @slovakgirl: In your *exact* context I wouldn't particularly care which I used - though it's worth pointing out that I'd be just as likely to ask ***Do they** find her there?* I'm simply taking issue with the implication in the answer here that which tense to use is *always* a personal / stylistic choice. There's definitely a potential distinction between ***going to*** and ***will*** - it's just that it's more or less "meaningless" in your example.

Answer (score 0):

They both work, however, there is a slight difference in the interrogative sentences:

1. "**is going to**" - a prediction depending on present evidence that we know about.
2. "**will**" - likelihood or certainty of intentions and actions of the future

So basically:

- "*Are they going to find her in that room?*" - You are predicting that they will so you are asking whether your prediction is true.
- "*Will they find her in that room?*" - You are uncertain that they will so you ask to know if you're right.

I'd say "**will**" implies that present evidence doesn't exactly point to any likelihood of them finding her whereas "**going to**" does.